# Using Anonymous Functions to return both original and modified variables

Tags: r, dplyr, functional-programming

Apologies in advance, I'm struggling with how to phrase this question and I hope my repex is sufficiently explanatory.

I'm trying to use a combination of [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse)'s mutate_ and anonymous functions to apply a transformation to a variable with the goal of returning the original variable and its transformed counter part to the data frame. I'm struggling on how to rename the output the function returns, while keeping the original. So far it only returns the modified copy of the original.

So far, my code takes the original inputs, and returns their transformed versions to the data such as in the current_output object. I tried to use assign() nested in return() to allow for more flexible naming and to return a new variable all together like in the desired_output object but no such luck.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(X1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
                   X1a = c(3, 3, 3, 3),
                   X2 = c(3, 3, 3, 3))

data%>%
  mutate_at(vars(X1,
                 X1a),
            function(x){ 
              X2 = get("X2", parent.frame())
              X1a = x * X2
              return(assign(paste(x, "X2", "_Product", sep = "_"), X1a))
            }) -> data2

desired_output <- data.frame(X1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
                           X1a = c(3, ,3 , 3),
                           X2 = c(3, 3, 3, 3),
                           X1_X2_Product = c(6, 6, 6, 6),
                           X1a_X2_Product = c(9, 9, 9, 9))

current_output <- data.frame(X1 = c(6, 6, 6, 6),
                             X1a = c(9, 9, 9, 9),
                             X2 = c(3, 3, 3, 3))
```

Comment: `data %>%  mutate(across(starts_with("X1"), ~ .x * X2, .names = "{.col}_X2_Product"))`. Don't use `mutate_at()` - it's been retired in favor of `across()`.

Comment: `data %>% mutate_at(vars(X1, X1a), list(X2_product = ~.x * X2))` or `data %>% mutate(across(c(X1, X1a), list(X2_product = ~.x * X2)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `across` and its `.names` argument:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(across(c(X1, X1a), ~ .x* X2, .names = "{.col}_X2_Product"))
```

```
  X1 X1a X2 X1_X2_Product X1a_X2_Product
1  2   3  3             6              9
2  2   3  3             6              9
3  2   3  3             6              9
4  2   3  3             6              9
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not respect all the constraints required by the question, but is here for comedic effect:

```
library(base)  # I know...

data$X1_X2_Product  <- data$X1  * data$X2
data$X1a_X2_Product <- data$X1a * data$X2
```

Comment: I know this will work but in the data Im working on I have to apply this transformation  to about 50 or so variables. Im working off the "if you copy it more than three times it should be a function" rule.

Comment: @Araph7 I understand, sure. The comedic effect I was counting on is about how impenetrable the `tidyverse` code is, compared to the basic operations on a plain  `data.frame`.